# Using EPPlus library to replace formulas by their values in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I've read that **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** would be the easiest way to replace formulas by their values in Excel but it requires to have Office installed.  Since I will need to deploy on a Windows Server (2008 or 2012), I am looking for the best and/or simplest way to accomplish that using **EPPlus**.

Adding formulas is well documented, e.g.

```
currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Formula = "SUM(C2:C3)";
```

But I cannot find any example of replacing entire worksheets of formulas by their equivalent values.  Basically the Copy followed by the Paste Special option in Excel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dont think there is any kind of function built into Epplus that will do that for you en masse.  But you can take advantage of the fact that the `Cells` collection of the `Worksheet` only contains entries for cells with content.  So something like this should not be too painful performance-wise:

```
currentWorksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 5;
currentWorksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 15;
currentWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Formula = "SUM(C2:C3)";

currentWorksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 15;
currentWorksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 25;
currentWorksheet.Cells["D4"].Formula = "SUM(D2:D3)";

//Calculate the formulas and the overwrite them with their values
currentWorksheet.Cells.Calculate();
foreach (var cell in currentWorksheet.Cells.Where(cell => cell.Formula != null))
    cell.Value = cell.Value;
```

Comment: Thx Ernie.  Something odd is happening.  When I test it with a simple file (2 sheets and a single formula), all works fine.  Then when I try to apply it to my working file, I get an InvalidOperationException error (Error saving file).

Comment: @CrnaKrv  Thats a tough one.  It could be something beyond what Epplus can handle since the orginal file was probably generated by excel itself.  If you can pull in the source code of Epplus and debug.

Comment: If the purpose is to replace the formula with its calculated value, I guess you should change _cell.Value = cell.Value_ to _cell.Formula = string.Empty_ after you have called Calculate()

The InvalidOperationException is tough as Earnie says, but one possible reason could be that the workbook that EPPlus tries to save is opened by another program/process (for example Excel).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 3 years old, but if you're reading this now, EPPlus now has the function `.ClearFormulas()` that does just that, simply do

```
yourSheetHere.Calculate();   
yourSheetHere.ClearFormulas();
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: I had a couple worksheets full of formulas like '//server/path/to/other/[workbook.xlsx]Tab'!Address. EPPlus was just silently bailing, I suppose, while evaluating a formula chain involving these. Calling ClearFormulas() on those tabs allows the workbook to actually calculate. Thank you!